# How to compare two things in qunit test?

Tags: javascript, function, unit-testing, qunit

Qunit test to check if two things are equal.

I have 2 variables i want to compare.
var currentVector = scene.up;
var expectedVector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );

they return the following:
[image: variables return]

```
assert.equal( currentVector, expectedVector, "Vector y is up in current scene");
```

but the console returns

[image: unit test error]

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation for `equal`](https://api.qunitjs.com/assert/equal)

> The `equal` assertion uses the simple comparison operator (==) to compare the actual and expected arguments.

In JavaScript, one object is not equal to another object unless both are the same reference.

```js
const o = {a: 1}
console.log('o == {a: 1}:', o == {a: 1})

const t = o
console.log('o == t:', o == t)
```

Simply use [`deepEqual`](https://api.qunitjs.com/assert/deepEqual) instead

```
assert.deepEqual(currentVector, expectedVector, "...")
```